# username in table1 and password in table 2 in php code

Tags: php, authentication, relation

I have a username in table1 and password in table 2. What is the syntax to login?

How can I make a login function if I have two tables:

```
TABLE1 NAME: accounts | COLUMN: acc_id, password, mem_id
TABLE2 NAME: members  | COLUMN: mem_id, firstname
```

I want to make the "firstname" as $username and make "password" as $password. I have code here, but I can't continue as I don't know whether it's right or not.

```
$sqlacc="SELECT * FROM members INNER JOIN accounts ON 
account.acc_id=members.mem_id WHERE members.firstname='$username' and accounts.password='$password'";
$resultacc = mysql_query($sqlacc);
$countacc = mysql_num_rows($resultacc);
$rowacc = mysql_fetch_array($resultacc, MYSQL_NUM);

if($countacc==1){
$_SESSION['idontknow']=$rowacc[0];
$_SESSION['idontknow']=$rowacc[1];
header("location:content/index.php");
}
```

Comment: First, can you get rid of the all-caps and the "plz"s?

Comment: okay okay. sorry, this is my first time here. :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
session_start();

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_username', 'mysql_password');

mysql_select_db('dbname', $link);

$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);        
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

$sqlacc=" select * ".
        " from members m ".
        " inner join accounts a on a.mem_id=m.mem_id ".
        " where a.password='".$password."' and m.firstname='".$username."'";

$result = mysql_query($sqlacc);
$countacc = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($countacc==1){
    $rowacc = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $_SESSION['memId']=$rowacc[0];
    $_SESSION['accId']=$rowacc[2];
    header("Location:content/index.php");
}
```

In your query the **joining condition** is wrong

```
account.acc_id=members.mem_id
```

Note: You can perform join on any two columns only the criteria is they must have same ***data-type and size***.

Comment: how about in this code after login.<br/>

    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

    $sqlacc="SELECT * FROM members 
    INNER JOIN accounts ON account.mem_id =members.mem_id 
    WHERE members.firstname='$username' and accounts.password='$password'";
    $resultacc = mysql_query($sqlacc);
    $countacc = mysql_num_rows($resultacc);
    $rowacc = mysql_fetch_array($resultacc, MYSQL_NUM);

    if($countacc==1){
    $_SESSION['______']=$rowacc[0];
    $_SESSION['______']=$rowacc[1];
    header("location: index.php");
    }

Comment: its not working. but i know your code is right. this my real problem [MYPROBLEM]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109081/not-yet-solve-login-username-firstname-in-table1-and-password-in-table2

Comment: @DanielReyes ,What is "my real problem".You have to use only session variable name their.Do you using session which is created by someone

Comment: sorry if i am so disturbance.. hehehe.
my real problem is in this link..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109081/not-yet-solve-login-username-firstname-in-table1-and-password-in-table2

Comment: @DanielReyes checkout session settings http://support.qualityunit.com/021373-How-To-Enable-Session-Support-for-PHP

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

In your query join condition wrongly mapped (**account.acc_id=members.mem_id**)

```
SELECT * FROM members 
INNER JOIN account ON account.mem_id =members.mem_id 
WHERE members.firstname='$username' and accounts.password='$password'";


$sqlacc="SELECT * FROM members INNER JOIN accounts ON 
account.mem_id =members.mem_id WHERE members.firstname='$username' and accounts.password='$password'";
```

Comment: Is your condition correct account.mem_id =members.mem_id ? table name is accounts

Comment: how about in this code after login.<br/>

    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

    $sqlacc="SELECT * FROM members 
    INNER JOIN accounts ON account.mem_id =members.mem_id 
    WHERE members.firstname='$username' and accounts.password='$password'";
    $resultacc = mysql_query($sqlacc);
    $countacc = mysql_num_rows($resultacc);
    $rowacc = mysql_fetch_array($resultacc, MYSQL_NUM);

    if($countacc==1){
    $_SESSION['______']=$rowacc[0];
    $_SESSION['______']=$rowacc[1];
    header("location: index.php");
    }

Comment: not yet. because some of my code is not right... code above that have error. 

if($countacc==1){
    $rowacc = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $_SESSION['idontknow']=$rowacc[0];
    $_SESSION['idontknow']=$rowacc[1];